# My Reload code does not work on Edge but does on Chrome

Tags: javascript, refresh, microsoft-edge, reload

I am trying to refresh my screen after going back to it.

I go back to it with the code:

```
  window.history.back();
```

My 'back' page has this function that works on chrome:

```
(function () {
    console.log("anon function");
    window.onpageshow = function(event) {
        console.log("onpageshow");
        if (event.persisted) {
            console.log("event.persisted");
            window.location.reload();
        }
    };
})();
```

On Edge is see "anon function" and "onpageshow" on the console but not "event.persisted"

Anyone give me a more browser friendly approach. W3Schools says event.persisted works on Edge.

Running Version 114.0.1823.86 (Official build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `event.persisted` is always `false` in Edge. But when we open Network tab in F12 devtools, we can see that the previous page is from disk cache: [image]. That might be some issue with Edge identifying `persisted` property. For this issue, you can provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge.

As a workaround for this issue in Edge, you can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to identify if the page needs refresh. When go back, you need to set a new `sessionStorage`:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('refresh', 'true');
window.history.back();
```

On the back page, you can identify if refresh is needed by getting the `sessionStorage` and remove it after reload:

```
(function () {
    console.log("anon function");
    window.onpageshow = function (event) {
        console.log("onpageshow");
        if (event.persisted) {
            console.log("event.persisted");
            window.location.reload();
        }
        else {
            if (sessionStorage.getItem('refresh') === 'true') {
                location.reload();
            }
            sessionStorage.removeItem('refresh');
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Great idea - I should have thought of that. THANK YOU! And thank you for such a clear answer!!